# How to find what is creating a .txt file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a strange situation.  I've caused strange situations before, but now it's happening to me. I have a .txt file ( log.txt) being created on a server drive and I don't know where it's coming from.

The contents of the .txt file say the actual date and the actual time an application process ran, but this the format of what's in the .txt file:

> (date) (time) AM    Starting Job: (date) (time) AM

I've checked a number of things to try to see what's causing this.  I have identified a SQL Server Agent Job that runs at that specific time.  It runs a SSIS package.  Part of that package runs a PowerShell script that starts 16 processes of an application.

The txt file is defiantly showing data of when the PowerShell script is executing the 16 or so Start-Process's in that script.

- The agent job doesn't have any steps to create such a file
- The SSIS package doesn't have logging turned on. (Right-click the screen in Visual Studio > logging.)
- There are no tasks on the project to create the .txt file in the SSIS project.
- An application is running a process on part of this and I think that's what's creating it, but the developer doesn't think it's the app creating it.

Is there anything else I should check to see what's generating this?

Comment: If you believe the SSIS package is creating the file (whether it is the package itself or by proxy via an application call) have you tried turning on debugging, breakpointing various parts of the package, and stepping through while keeping an eye on the file directory?

Comment: have you looked at the powershell script you mentioned?  maybe that is creating the log file.

Comment: Try to desactivate the SSIS packages. Maybe the pscript is the main reason to have such file

Comment: Lock the file by setting permissions or read-only. Presumably whatever process that creates it will throw an error.

Comment: If you can catch the file while it's being created/written to then use SysInternals' `handle` tool to see which process is writing to it. ref: [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)

Comment: To answer the comments.  I don't believe the SSIS package is creating the file.  I've checked the XML file and there are not tasks in it that would reference '*log.txt'.  I have looked at the Powershell script and nothing in it creates a text file.

Comment: I did do a PowerShell search of the applications' DLL files and it did find the text of 'log.txt', which has me thinking it's the application creating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using SysInternals > ProcMon.  I scheduled the job at a time where I could start ProcMon and monitor the creation of the file.  In this case, it was the tool I thought it was.  The developer fixed the issue.

In case anyone else would like to learn more about SysInternals, here are a few links:

Info on SysInternals:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/

ProcMon:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Video on how to find issues from the creator of SysInternals:

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2016/BRK4028